# Flask - Cannot commit changes on view

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this Flask app deployed on a server.

Everything works fine except for the views where I need to db.session.commit() anytihing. I've been looking for circular imports and db engine stuff but I can't seem to understand why it doesn't work.

Below I post my **init**.py and one of the views I can't seem to make work.

```
 #__init__.py

from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import config
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

bootstrap = Bootstrap()
moment = Moment()
db = SQLAlchemy()

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

def create_app(config_name):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
        config[config_name].init_app(app)

        bootstrap.init_app(app)
        moment.init_app(app)
        db.app = app
        db.init_app(app)
        db.create_all()
        login_manager.init_app(app)

        #BLUEPRINTS
        from main import main as main_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

        from auth import auth as auth_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix = '/auth')

        from api import api as api_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint, url_prefix = '/api')

        return app

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The config.py file where the db settings are defined

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'hard to guess string'
    SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN = True
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
    # MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.live.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    # Variáveis de configuração definidas na linha de comandos por motivos de segurança
    MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
    MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
    ORGANITE_MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Organite]'
    ORGANITE_MAIL_SENDER = '*****@hotmail.com'
    ORGANITE_ADMIN = '*****@hotmail.com'

    @staticmethod
    def init_app(app):
        pass

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
        DEBUG = True
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///data-dev.sqlite'

class TestConfig(Config):
        TESTING = True
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('TEST_DATABASE_URL') or \
                'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data-test.sqlite')

class ProductionConfig(Config):
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
                'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')

config = {
        'development': DevelopmentConfig,
        'testing': TestConfig,
        'production': ProductionConfig,
        'default': DevelopmentConfig
}
```

Then on my api blueprint one of the views that don't work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import jsonify, request, session, redirect, url_for, current_app
from flask.ext.login import login_user, logout_user, login_required, \
    current_user
from .. import db
from ..models import User
from flask.ext.login import login_required
from ..decorators import admin_required, permission_required
from . import api
import cx_Oracle
import datetime
import json
import os

os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".UTF8"

#Remover utilizador > JSON
@api.route('/delete/<id>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
@admin_required
def del_user(id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(num_mec=id).first()
    if user is not None:
        try:
            db.session.delete(user)
            db.session.commit()
            status = 'Sucesso'
        except:
            status = 'Falhou'
    else:
        status='Falhou'
    db.session.close()
    return jsonify({'result': status})
```

No matter the changes I make the result will always be 'Falhou', meaning the db.session.commit() failed.

I don't even know how to see log errors for this kind of things and I can't seem to understand why it doesn't work.

Please, help, I am running out of time to finish this project.

Comment: Or you just don't have the user in your database so `user` is `None`. You probably want to specify that `<id>` is an integer: `<int:id>`

Comment: You should adf logging to your application. And you are masking any error message with the generic `try` / `except` block. For debugging you should add `raise` to the `except` block to re-raise the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The problem was with the permissions for my db file. It's been two days around this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, unfortunately, the real cause of the error is being obscured by the `try: except` block which suppresses the error and just handles it by returning the failure result.

Remove the `try: except` and you will see the cause of the session commit failure in the crash log that Flask generates (in this case, as you mentioned in the comment, there was not sufficient permissions on the database file).

As a general rule, unless an exception is expected and must be handled gracefully, it's better to let it crash and burn with maximum error reporting (at least in debug mode) so that bugs don't slip by silently unnoticed. Since there is no general use-case where you would expect a failed commit to be normal behaviour, you should not be wrapping it in a `try: except` block.

Comment: even better, write the (except:) as (except Exception as error_message:) and then, print the error_message. Also, try using an IDE with debugging and put a breakpoint on that try.